# $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan 5x}{\tan 3x}$

Tags: limits

Can you help me with this limit please?

> $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan 5x}{\tan 3x}$$

WolframAlpha gave the answer as $\frac{3}{5}$ but I have no idea how to proceed. We learn to substitute and normally calculate, but this gives me different result as alpha. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your efforts to solve the problem

Comment: I would write $x=\pi/2+y$, so that one can consider the limit as $y\to0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I did the same in my answer

Comment: You could find the Taylor series expansion and use a  suitable substitution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the trig. identity: $\cot(\frac{π}{2}-\alpha)=\tan(\alpha)$

Using this equation, substituting: $y=\frac{π}{2}-x$, and considering that $\tan$ in periodic with period $π$ (and thus $\cot(5y)=\cot(\frac{π}{2}-5x)$), we get:

$\lim_{x \to \frac{π}{2}}\frac{\tan(5x)}{\tan(3x)}=\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\tan(3y)}{\tan(5y)}=\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\tan(3y)}{3y}\frac{5y}{\tan(5y)}\frac{3}{5}=\frac{3}{5}$

Comment: In the last step you need to add a factor $\frac35$.

Comment: @gimusi right, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplify $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan 5x}{\tan 3x} = \left( \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos 3x}{\cos 5x} \right)\left( \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin 5x}{\sin 3x} \right) = -\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos 3x}{\cos 5x}$$
and apply l'Hopital.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-y$ with $y\to 0$

$$\frac{\tan 5x}{\tan 3x}=\frac{\tan \left(\frac{5\pi}{2}-5y\right)}{\tan \left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-3y\right)}=\frac{\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-5y\right)}{\tan \left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-3y\right)}=\frac{\tan \left(-3y\right)}{\tan \left(-5y\right)}=\frac{\tan \left(-3y\right)}{-3y}\frac{-5y}{\tan \left(-5y\right)}\frac{3}{5}\to$$
$$\to1\cdot1\cdot\frac35=\frac35$$

Comment: Using the fact that tan is odd, you can remove the minus in your passages

Comment: @gabrielecassese Yes it is absolutely correct, it is possible to change the minus sign, but it works good also in this way!

Comment: Yes sure, it was only a matter of form. It hurted me a little these equations with all of those minus

Comment: @gimusi other solution is clear for me, but I don't understand what is that y .. can you give me please simpler explanation? I am fully new in limits. I don't want just copy solution, I want to learn it also. Thanks in advance

Comment: @DenisStephanov It is a change of variable, when you deal with limit which are not at 0 or at $\infty$ it is often convenient to change variable in order to deal with a limit at 0 or \infty. In this case since $x\to \pi/2$ then $y\to0$.

Comment: @gabrielecassese I apologize for it but if it does not bother you I would leave them! In this way our solution will be a little bit different :)

Comment: @gimusi Yes sure :)